# How from mvnrepository.com can I get the jar and the pom of one library?

Tags: java, maven, mvn-repo

How can I retrieve from mvnrepository.com the jar and the pom that correspond to

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.exoplayer/exoplayer-ui
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.6.1'
```

Else if not possible from mvnrepository.com from where else I can retrieve this jar ?

Answer (score 0):

For this you can usually look into the repository.

Here is the one at Github: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

But this is a gradle project, so you'll rather need to look at the `build.gradle`.

You can also find the `pom.xml` in the maven repository for the latest release: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.exoplayer/exoplayer-ui/2.18.1

On the releases page there is just the code bundled as a zip, so in this case you'd need to clone the repository and build it by yourself.

Comment: thanks, on https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer I can not find the 2.6.1, I do not need the last version, only the 2.6.1. how to look at the build.gradle? I don't even know what is it :(